# How to handle a video call through voip and call kit

Tags: ios, swift, voip, callkit, pushkit

I'm new to Apples callKit and Pushkit. i'm using [OpenTok](https://tokbox.com/developer/) in my application for video and audio call handling. To handle native like calling in my app i'm using VOIP with callkit . Audio native call is working fine, When user interacts with the native UI of callkit it goes to background the application gets to foreground. Has i looked into speaker box of apple documentation about call kit. It has some Intent handlers to handle calls

Please can anyone Help me out of by giving any idea about handling video and audio calls natively
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same with OpenTok. As far as I'm aware you can't handle video calls natively from the lock screen, however you can use OpenTok with CallKit for just audio. See [this link](https://github.com/opentok/CallKit)

Comment: Thankyou! I have implemented the same. Audio call is working but audio is not clear.If possible can you please share me how you have done.When did you activate the audio for call

Comment: Actually I haven't used CallKit, I'm just doing video, but maybe it could be your internet making the quality unclear? It's hard to say

Comment: I'm using react-native-twilio-webrtc with callkeep to handle callkit for video calling. It works fine so far but creates issue while ios device is locked. any idea to handle it while device is in lock state?

Answer (score 0):

CallKit have a property `supportsVideo` of `CXProviderConfiguration` and one property `hasVideo` of `CXHandle`.
It's working fine for me. Check this below demo link.

https://websitebeaver.com/callkit-swift-tutorial-super-easy

```
func setupVdeoCall() {
        let config = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "My App")
        config.iconTemplateImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "pizza")!)
        config.ringtoneSound = "ringtone.caf"
        config.includesCallsInRecents = false;
        config.supportsVideo = true;
        let provider = CXProvider(configuration: config)
        provider.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
        let update = CXCallUpdate()
        update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: "Pete Za")
        update.hasVideo = true
        provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: UUID(), update: update, completion: { error in })
    }
```